# What do you call a floor made of glass so you can see through the floor?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if this has a particular name, but I am thinking it might, because I see it a lot on modern bridges and tall towers that serve as tourist attraction. What is it called, is there a name for such a thing?

Comment: I'd call them "terrifying" and "no thank you"   (comment cos NAA and funny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of tourist attraction is often called a "glass observation deck", or sometimes just an "observation deck", although there are also observation decks without a glass floor.

If you have a glass floor in some other context, I'd just call it a glass floor, or maybe a glass deck if it's outdoors.

Answer (score 3):

The most general, basic term for that, is ***glass floor***.

Sometimes, the term for something is just simply calling it what it is. In specific instances, a different term might be used, but they are limited to specific situations.

Comment: As confirmation, that's what Wikipedia calls them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_floor